# Repository pattern interfaces- Best practices?

Tags: c#, .net, repository-pattern

I'm learning about Repository Pattern and I found many code examples but all are almost the same so I have doubts to that respect, for example this design:

```
     public interface IRepository<T> 
     {
        void Add(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        IList<T> GetAll();
     }
     public interface IPostRepository
     {
        int GetComentCount();
     }
     public class EFRepository<T>: IRepository<T>
     {
        public void Add(T entity){ /*implementation...*/ }
        public void Update(T entity){ /*implementation...*/ }   
        public void Delete(T entity){ /*implementation...*/ }
        public IList<T> GetAll(){ /*implementation...*/ }
     }
     public class PostRepository: EFRepository<Post>, IPostRepository
     {
        public int GetComentCount(){ /*implementation...*/ }
     }
     public class UnitOfWork: IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
     {
        IPostRepository PostRepository {get;}
     }
```

I can do this:

```
    IUnitOfWork UoW = new UnitOfWork();
    int nComments = UoW.PostRepository.GetComentCount();
```

but not this: (obviously)

```
    var collection = UoW.PostRepository.GetAll();
```

What I have to do? Must I create another property in UoW and return an IRepository?
Must I create an interface for every Repository with no CRUD operations (for example IPostRepository)? Must a concrete repository inherit from EFRepository class and the interface at a time (for example: class PostRepository: EFRepository, IPostRepository{})?

What do you think?

PD: Pardon my poor english.

Comment: If you make `IPostRepository` inherit `IRepository` then it will work.

Comment: Same comment as @BenRobinson. Also, if you are going for best practices, avoid returning a concrete class like List<T>, return ICollection<T>, IList<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T> or some other interface.

Comment: @braintechd you're right I'll update that code.

Comment: _"Must a concrete repository inherit from EFRepository class and the interface at a time?"_ - yes, if you want it to inherit the base `EFRepository` implementation.

Comment: @BenRobinson you are right, I deleted my prevoius comment, that was a lapsus. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use repository pattern with an ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change IPostRepository to inherit from IRepository, you are simply extending the interface surface, so you don't need to redefine all the methods.

For example, with this change:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IList<T> GetAll();
}
public interface IPostRepository : IRepository<int>
{
    int GetComentCount();
}
public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public void Add(T entity) { Console.WriteLine("Works"); }
    public void Update(T entity) { /*implementation...*/ }
    public void Delete(T entity) { /*implementation...*/ }
    public IList<T> GetAll() { return null; }
}
public class PostRepository : EFRepository<int>, IPostRepository
{
    public int GetComentCount() { return 0; }
}

public interface IUnitOfWork
{

}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    public IPostRepository PostRepository { get { return new PostRepository(); } }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The following code will print **Works**:

```
UnitOfWork t = new UnitOfWork();
t.PostRepository.Add(1);
```

Basically, your PostRepository does not need to reimplement the Add/Update/Delete methods as that interface contract is already present in the base class EFRepository and will be used. IPostRepository will force you to only provide the extended interface contract.

As for best practices, I don't think there is a single good solution. I try to go with the inherit approach, but I have seen good production code that has ReadOnly/Add/AddUpdate/etc. repository interfaces for composition.

P.S. I changed *Post* class with *int* in the example to avoid defining a whole new class.

Comment: thank you. In my case IPostRepository sould be generic (IPostRepository<T>:IRepository<T>)because I have interfaces in a separate project without reference to EF project.